# Selecting rows which match condition of group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame `df` which looks as follows:

```
ID    Timestamp    x    y
1     10           322  222
1     12           234  542           
1     14           22   523
2     55           222  76
2     56           23   87
2     58           322  5436
3     100          322  345
3     150          22   243
3     160          12   765
3     170          78   65
```

Now, I would like to keep all rows where the timestamp is between 12 and 155. This I could do by `df[df["timestamp"] >= 12 & df["timestamp"] <= 155]`. But I would like to have only rows included where all timestamps in the corresponding ID group are within the range. So in the example above it should result in the following dataframe:

```
ID    Timestamp    x    y
2     55           222  76
2     56           23   87
2     58           322  5436
```

For `ID == 1` and `ID == 3` not all timestamps of the rows are in the range that's why they are not included.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and using [`all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) to check if all items in the group matches the condition:

```
df[df.groupby('ID').Timestamp.transform(lambda x: x.between(12,155).all())]
```

---

```
   ID  Timestamp    x     y
3   2         55  222    76
4   2         56   23    87
5   2         58  322  5436
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine groupby("ID") and filter:

```
df.groupby("ID").filter(lambda x: x.Timestamp.between(12, 155).all())

   ID  Timestamp    x     y
3   2         55  222    76
4   2         56   23    87
5   2         58  322  5436
```